# Why do dash to dock icons disappear after sleep mode? Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu-dock, 21.10, dash-to-dock

After entering in sleep mode, when I log back in again, the icons in the dock have disappeared. I'm using Dash to Dock extension.

[image]

becomes

[image]

It is even more frustrating the fact that I can't even move between windows using alt+tab - it's like all open windows are also gone.

I upgraded from Ubuntu 21.04 few days ago.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Dash to dock is not supported by gnome 40 , So you have compiled it yourself , So it's obvious that it contains bugs , And this is a common bug.

Comment: I agree to the answer by @vanadium , Currently there is no official version of dash to dock. But one can use extensions like , Ubuntu dock , floating dock , dash to panel etc.

Comment: Testing floating dock, thanks

Comment: I am glad it It helped

Comment: BTW I personally don't like floating dock , because it is not too configurable

Comment: Remove and reinstall Dash to Dock, as their latest update is Gnome 4.x compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your extension is not compatible with the version of Gnome Shell that comes with your upgraded Ubuntu version.

If you install software outside of the official repositories, then you are responsible for whether it works or not. Dash to Dock is not supported software in Ubuntu. Thus, when you upgrade to a newer Ubuntu version, it may break.

Remove the Dash to Dock extension. If there is an updated version, you may take the responsability to install that one instead. However, it is safer to just use the Ubuntu Dock extension. That is based on Dash to Dock and packaged specifically to work with your current Ubuntu version.

Comment: The latest DtD is Gnome 4.x compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue on Ubuntu 21.10 with Gnome 40.4.0. It was resolved by switching off the Built in Ubuntu Dock Extension.

Steps:

1. Install the Dash-to-Dock extension from here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/
2. Under Applications > Extensions > Built-in, deselect the Ubuntu Dock toggle (see screenshot below)
3. Restart: ALT+F2, "r",

This solved the issue described by OP that the icons in the dock disappear after a suspend. Hope it helps someone running into this issue

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue, but once I disable built-in "Ubuntu-Dock", in the extensions, everything seems to be fixed.